# How to classify URLs?

Tags: ruby, classification

I have a set of urls, example:

```
https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=456789
https://www.facebook.com/messages/78134
https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=123
https://www.facebook.com/messages/781234
https://www.facebook.com/45/settings/781234/ab
https://www.facebook.com/48/settings/989213/ef
```

The data set has at least 100 urls, with say 5-6 types. What I expect is:

```
[
  ['https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=456789',
   'https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=123'],
  ['https://www.facebook.com/messages/781234',
   'https://www.facebook.com/messages/78134'],
  ['https://www.facebook.com/45/settings/781234/ab',
   'https://www.facebook.com/48/settings/989213/ef']
]
```

How do I classify them? There is no learning input.

Comment: It's a non-trivial problem. What do you have so far?

Comment: You are classifying it in some way according to whatever criteria you have in mind. Why are you asking that to us? How do you think we are supposed to read your mind and tell you what you have in mind?

Comment: I do not have a solution yet, I'm trying to find out if what could be a better way of solving this.

Comment: I was expecting some sort of easy implementation of a learning algorithm. Apologies if the question isn't well-formed.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't well defined, but this seems to work according to the desired output:

```
require 'uri'

URL_DIVISIONS = %w[profile messages settings]
URL_DIVISION_REGEX = Regexp.union(URL_DIVISIONS)

urls = %w[
  https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=456789
  https://www.facebook.com/messages/78134
  https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=123
  https://www.facebook.com/messages/781234
  https://www.facebook.com/45/settings/781234/ab
  https://www.facebook.com/48/settings/989213/ef
]

pp urls.group_by{ |url|
  URI.parse(url).path[URL_DIVISION_REGEX] 
}
```

Which outputs:

```
{"profile"=>
  ["https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=456789",
  "https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=123"],
"messages"=>
  ["https://www.facebook.com/messages/78134",
  "https://www.facebook.com/messages/781234"],
"settings"=>
  ["https://www.facebook.com/45/settings/781234/ab",
  "https://www.facebook.com/48/settings/989213/ef"]}
```

If you need the list without the dividing information, use:

```
pp urls.group_by{ |url|
  URI.parse(url).path[URL_DIVISION_REGEX] 
}.values
```

Which outputs:

```
[["https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=456789",
  "https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=123"],
["https://www.facebook.com/messages/78134",
  "https://www.facebook.com/messages/781234"],
["https://www.facebook.com/45/settings/781234/ab",
  "https://www.facebook.com/48/settings/989213/ef"]]
```

I'd keep it as a hash though, and use the URL_DIVISIONS array to loop over the keys, extracting the values as needed.

Comment: Although nice, but I think he's looking for a self-learning classifier.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a self-learning version. You don't specify the exact criteria for learning, so you probably want to tweak the regexp, but maybe you can use it as a starting point:

```
require 'uri'

urls = %w[
  https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=456789
  https://www.facebook.com/messages/78134
  https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=123
  https://www.facebook.com/messages/781234
  https://www.facebook.com/45/settings/781234/ab
  https://www.facebook.com/48/settings/989213/ef
]

pp urls.group_by { |url|
  (URI.parse(url).path.match(/[a-z]+/) || ["unknown"])[0]
}
```

Output:

```
{"messages"=>
  ["https://www.facebook.com/messages/78134",
   "https://www.facebook.com/messages/781234"],
 "profile"=>
  ["https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=456789",
   "https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=123"],
 "settings"=>
  ["https://www.facebook.com/45/settings/781234/ab",
   "https://www.facebook.com/48/settings/989213/ef"]}
```

Comment: Thanks - this seems to be a good option. Basically, I need to find out how to create a regexp for every set.